# 5th Gear slipping out when letting off gas pedal in Toyota Landcruiser HJ75 - 1990)

Tags: toyota, manual-transmission, land-cruiser

Whilst driving, when I take my foot off the accelerator in 5th gear, the stick/vehicle goes into neutral. It's doing this more and more.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Stick shift (Manual Transmission) or automatic transmission?

Comment: @zipzit  It's a stick

Answer (score 3):

I have this problem occasionally on my old Subaru Forester as well. My research indicates that it's essentially just down to wear in the transmission or connected parts.

In particular for my car [a backed-off nut on the rear of the transmission's input shaft](http://www.subaruforester.org/vbulletin/f89/5th-gear-pops-out-43519/#post490733) is often implicated.

I'm not familiar with the specific makeup of yours, but easy-ish stuff to check would include:

- slop and wear in the linkage between the shifter lever and the transmission (including any stabilizer bar or mounts that may be present)
- the transmission and possibly engine mounts
- slop and wear in the driveshaft, any of its u-joints, and its connection to the transmission

Beyond that, I think you'll be opening the tranny case to look at bearings.